# Insert data into asp.net table through code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a table in asp.net page and i want to insert the data which will be recieved from service call through c# code behind. Any idea on how to do this.

Below is my table.

```
<table id="DataTable" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I just need to insert values recieved from service call in place of &nbsp.

Comment: What about placing labels there instead of &nbsp?

Comment: @Scott : Im just trying whether its possible with table

Comment: @Chandu- Indyaah   OK , yes ! you can.  An easy way is add runat = "server" on your table tag.  And you can access it in your .cs file.  Then , you could insert everything as you like.

Comment: @Chandu- Indyaah and if you add asp:Label ,  I donnt know how many td you would have.  I think you'd better general it dynamic by your code.

Comment: @Mythje : Why did you just comment? you could have answered it ... Label did my job.. thanks :)

Comment: @Scott : Only about 2 columns and 5 rows of data . So i preferred this way

Comment: @Chandu- Indyaah Because it's just like 1 sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your aspx page *asp:Label* controls and assign the values from code behind by accessing them using Id.

Inside .aspx

```
  <asp:Label Id="lblName" runat="server">
```

In code behind

```
  lblName.Text = "Value from Service";
```

If you need to repeat this table use GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Use the asp:Table control instead.. It gives you much more control from server side than a normal html tag :)

And it ofc render as a normal table client side

Answer (score 1):

If you persist on working with pure html table you can use an new/old style to control it.

like so:

```
<table>
   <% foreach ( var o in objects ) { %>
    <!--UserControl -->
     <tr>
         <td> can put here data like so: <%= o.Id %> </td>
     </tr>  
     <!--UserControl -->
   <%}%>
</table>
```

or you can use Repeater and Bind data if it's dynamic.

If data is not dynamic and your table will not grow or change size, you can use a little OOP for this.

like so:
create in your class properties and then populate them.
public string MyLabel { get; set; }

put something in page load.

in aspx do it like so..

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td> <%= MyLabel %> </td>
     </tr>           
</table>
```

or

```
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td> <asp:Label ID=|"myText" runat="server"/> </td>
         </tr>           
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the table Html server side control. Try this:

```
<table runat="server" id="DataTable" class="style1">
<tr>
    <td id="td1" runat="server">
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td id="td2" runat="server">
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td id="td3" runat="server">
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td id="td4" runat="server">
        &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Now in the code behind

```
td1.InnerText="xx" or td1.InnerHtml=..
```